# Arrow keys in python shell do not have desired behavior in linux

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, interpreter

I could get the arrow keys to work in the python shell in linux after installing `readline`. But now there is another issue. Consider the following statements:

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = 2
>>> c = 3
>>> a = 1
>>> (here down arrow key does not work)
```

After entering `c = 3`, I use the up arrow to get to `a = 1`. **After pressing Enter**, the down arrow key gives nothing. In Windows, it gives me
`b = 2`, which is what I want. But, in linux, I have to use the up arrow
again to get to `b = 2`. This is a problem when I want to repeat a 
sequence of statements (I have to use the up arrow key to get to each statement).

Any ideas on how I can correct this?

Comment: I have a feeling that might just be "how it works". After you enter `a = 1` a second time, it becomes the last command in the history buffer, so pressing the down arrow does nothing as you're already at the last line. There are lots of ways to customise `readline` but I can't think of one that would achieve this.

Comment: Then how does it work in Windows? Though in windows, I don't have `readline` installed. It probably uses `libedit`.